# EF Linq to Entity assign array members in class initializer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

The following is a code snippet that gets the data desired from DB and uses class initializer to initialize the property members:

```
 var list =
            (from spcdata_tb in _dbContext.SPCDATA_TB
             from wh_master_tb in _dbContext.WH_MASTER_TB
             where spcdata_tb.FACTORY_CODE == factoryCode
             && spcdata_tb.LINE_CODE == lineCode
             && spcdata_tb.MODEL_NO == modelNumber
             && spcdata_tb.FACTORY_CODE == wh_master_tb.WH_CODE
             && spcdata_tb.LINE_CODE == wh_master_tb.LINE_CODE
             select new SPCMeasureData() 
             { 
               operDateString = spcdata_tb.DATA_WDATE, 
               operTimeString = spcdata_tb.DATA_WTIME,
               inputTimeString = spcdata_tb.DATA_ITIME,
               modelNumString = spcdata_tb.MODEL_NO,
               DataList[0] = spcdata_tb.DATA1,
               DataList[1] = spcdata_tb.DATA2,
               DataList[2] = spcdata-tb.DATA3
             });
```

However, it's throwing a compiler error that DataList[0] and DataList[1] cannot be found.

```
public class SPCMeasureData
{
    public DateTime operDateString { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? operTimeString { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? inputTimeString { get; set; }
    public string modelNumString { get; set; }
    public string modelNameString { get; set; }
    public string lotNumString { get; set; }
    public int dataSeqString { get; set; }
    public string factoryCodeString { get; set; }
    public string factoryNameString { get; set; }
    public string lineCodeString { get; set; }
    public string lineNameString { get; set; }
    public string cusNameString { get; set; }
    public string equipNumString { get; set; }
    public float?[] dataList = new float?[30];

    public float?[] DataList
    {
        get { return dataList; }
        set { dataList = value; }
    }
}
```

I suspect that while the actual array member of DataList can be initialized from class initializer, its array members cannot be assigned by this same way.

Is there a way of overcoming this issue?

Comment: The only way I guess is to initialize the array within the object initializer like  `DataList= new[]{spcdata_tb.DATA1,spcdata_tb.DATA2,spcdata-tb.DATA3}`. but not sure if this will work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object initializer syntax can only recognize direct member of the object. So in this case it can recognize the array property, `DataList` but not `DataList[index]`. Solution to that is to use array initializer syntax. Similar thing happen when you have a complex property, a property that is of type another class. In that case, use another object initializer syntax. For example :

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public OtherClass ComplexProperty { get; set; }
    public float?[] ArrayFloatProperty { get; set; }
    public List<string> CollectionProperty { get; set; }
}
```

`MainObject` can be initialized this way :

```
var mainObj = new MainClass
              {
                    ArrayFloatProperty = new float? [] {0f, 2f, 3f},
                    ComplexProperty = new OtherClass { Prop1 = "string property" },
                    CollectionProperty = new List<string> { "str1", "str2", "str3" }
              };
```